# Why is the number of SNIRLostPackets so large?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am trying to simulate vehicular ad hoc networks using Veins 4.4, OMNeT++ 5.0 and SUMO 0.25.

There are only one-hop broadcast beacons in the vanet, and each vehicle sends 10 beacons/s. The size of each beacon is 4000 bits. And nic.mac1609_4.bitrate is 6Mbps.

In my simulation,there are 120 vehicles almost uniformly along the 2-km road, and the TX power of each vehicle is 200mW. After 20s' simulation, I select the vehicles in the middle part, and their SNIRLostPackets is almost 19000 and ReceivedBroadcasts is almost 3500, so the Packet Error Ratio is so high.
I read the codes and find:if there is one bit error in one packet, the packet is consedered to be not correctly received. Is my finding right?

The TX power is 200mW and vehicles are in each others' communication range. Then the network load at each vehicle is 4000*10*120 = 4.8Mbps < 6Mbps,so the number of SNIRLostPackets should not be so large?

Comment: What did you change related to the actual transmission in comparison to pure Veins 4.4? Try debugging your simulation in very simple scenarios (e.g. only 2 nodes) to find out whether something is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. I read the codes, and if a vehicle is receving one broadcasting message, the other arriving broadcasting message is thought to be lost because of collision. So I am considering add a buffering queue to restore received messages.